# C++ creating dynamic array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

```
#include "resistor.h"


void main() {
    srand(GetTickCount()); // Lewt's start by seeding the random number generator so that different runs of our program will always yield fifferent results
    Resistor * pResistor; // Pointer to a resistor class
    int numberOfResistors = 0;  // Variable will hold the user choice of the number of resistors to be created
    cout << "How many resistors do you want to create?" << endl;  // prompt user
    cin >> numberOfResistors;  // Allow the user to enter the number of resistors to be created
    pResistor = new Resistor[numberOfResistors];  // Create an array of objects of class resistor and assign its address to our pointer

    // You will notice that there is a logic error here. All the resistors will have the same value. This
    // is because they were all created at once. To address this issue we need to create each object
    // of the class resistor separately. This means using a loop. This will be up  to you to do
    // It should be a very easy fix
    for (int i = 0; i< numberOfResistors; i++) {  // This loop will be used to display the resistor values
        cout << "Resistor # " << i + 1 << " has a value of " << pResistor->getResistance() << " " << (char)234 << endl;  // Display value of resistor pointed to by pResistor
    }

    cout << "So far, we have created " << pResistor->getNumerOfResistors() << " resistor(s)" << endl; // Display total number of resistors
    delete[] pResistor; // Delete the array that was created and release the memory that was allocated.
}  // end of main
```

I'm am woriking with this code for a class assignment. As you can probably see in the comments there is a logic error that my instructor put in there and I need to fix it. I tried putting the `pResistor = new Resistor[numberOfResistors];` line inside a for loop that runs the number of times spcified by user input (instead of creating an array). The problem is still that each object is still created with the same value for `ResistorObject.resistance`

Any input would be much appreciated

EDIT: The following code is what i tried to explain above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResistors; i++) {
    pResistor = new Resistor[i];  // Create an array of objects of class resistor and assign its address to our pointer
}
```

This however will not compile as I get the error:

> error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'pResistor' used

Comment: How do you set the resistance? Is it specified in user defined (non default) constructor? Should you be using the RNG to do so?

Comment: You don't need to comment every line of code - we know C++. Over-commenting actually makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Vectors are the obvious approach like user3670482s answer shows. The vector contains many individual pointers to different resistors which each get allocated and can thus have their resistance set differently, but again how do you set the resistance? Also, are you supposed to be doing this without vectors?

Comment: Change `pResistor->getResistance()` to `pResistor[i].getRsistance()`  . Don't change your `new`

Comment: Your edit is memory leak central: it keeps trying to allocated different amounts of memory to the same pointer variable without anyway of you being able to free it again. Your code is trying to allocate 0 resistors to pResistor, then 1, then 2, then 3... etc.

Comment: Whoever gave you the GetResistance function, should also give you a setResistance function. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Use `vector<Resistor>`, reserve the vector, and use `emplace_back` function. If Resistor is not copyable, consider `vector<unique_ptr<Resistor>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
srand(GetTickCount());
Resistor * pResistor = NULL; 
vector<Resistor*> resList;
int numberOfResistors = 50; // Use your cin cout here
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfResistors; i++)
{
    pResistor = new Resistor;
    // Assuming some sort of pResistor->SetResistance( /* val */ )
    resList.push_back(pResistor);
}

for (int i = 0; i< numberOfResistors; i++) {  // This loop will be used to display the resistor values
    cout << "Resistor # " << i + 1 << " has a value of " << resList[i]->getResistance() << " " << (char)234 << endl;  // Display value of resistor pointed to by pResistor
}

cout << "number of resistors : " << resList.size() << endl;
```

Each resistor needs its own reference, and all the references must be added to an ordered list. std::vector is used to make ordered lists